# cellForItemAtIndexPath not called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, collectionview

I'm trying to push from a view controller to a collection view controller.

```
UICollectionViewLayout *collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
xraylab *xraylabvc = [[xraylab alloc]initWithCollectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:xraylabvc animated:YES];
```

The collection view controller will be displayed with a blank black screen.

`numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` returns 1

`numberOfItemsInSection` returns a non-zero integer

My problem is that `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not called.

Delegate and datasource of the collection view are set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Delegate and datasource of the collection view are set, datasource could be empty.

Answer (score 1):

`numberOfItemsInSection` should `return` `rowcount > 0` for `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to execute

Check `Delegate` and `datasource` of the `collection view` are `set`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy here is the code that worked.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *CollLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
UICollectionView *AttachmentsView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, CurrentY, 640, 300) collectionViewLayout:CollLayout];
//AttachmentsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[AttachmentsView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseCell"];
[VaribleStore SharedInstance].Attachments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor blueColor], nil];
AttachmentsView.delegate = self;
AttachmentsView.dataSource = self;
[self.ScrollView addSubview:AttachmentsView];
[AttachmentsView reloadData];
```

The key was to use the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, the reason is that UICollectionViewLayout is an abstract class, and can not be used for this purpose. after i made that switch ios called cellForItemAtIndexPath as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UICollectionViewLayout as is. It's an abstract base class and it has to be subclassed. You can use UICollectionViewFlowLayout for grid-like views if you don't want to write your own.